# SQL Server query tuning strategy

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, execution-plan, parallelism

I'm new to query tuning and have been using Brent Ozar's tools to identify costly queries on the server.

One query that is executed numerous times per minute is triggering warnings for:

- Forced Parameterization
- Parallel
- Parameter Sniffing
- Downlevel CE.

The biggest wait from the query store is **Parallelism** and this query is by far the biggest offender.

I'm look for some guidance on attacking this plan.
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyZRAYiNK

Comment: You should probably start by figuring out who's running test queries in prod: `AND ( ( prvdr . First_Name = 'test' and prvdr . Last_Name = 'test' ) or ( usr . first_name = 'test' and usr . last_name = 'test' ) )`

Comment: Can you include your SQL Server version, as well as your table schema and indexes? Also, any trace flags you have running, non-default database/server options enabled. Cost Threshold and MAXDOP settings would also be helpful. See [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: And post an Actual Execution Plan, not an Estimated Execution Plan.  Actual Execution Plans now include waits, elapsed time, and CPU used.  And note that Parallelism waits don't always indicate a problem, as they only indicate that _some_ thread was waiting.    See eg https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/making-parallelism-waits-actionable/ba-p/385691

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.